# Filter questions by reputaion

Tags: support, questions, search

Is it possible to filter questions by reputation of the author?
Just Something like `[favtag] [rep<5]` to show all the newcommer questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible to search based on OP's reputation. You may read all the [Advanced Search Options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

On a related note, low rep **is not equal to** a new commer. You would find users who have been a member of Stack Exchange community for couple of years but their reps are low possibly because they offer frequent bounties or are unable to spend much time here.